# How to replace values in a dataframe() based on corresponding values in a list()?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list and a dataframe. The data frame has has two columns, one for song, one for song type. I have a list of songs, for type one song.

```
allsongs <- data.frame("Song" = c(1, 2, "3A", "9C", 6, 5, "12B", "32A", 18, 27, 24, "1D"),
                        "Type" = 0)

type1songs <- list(c(1, 2, "32A", 6, "1D"))
```

I would like to use this list to apply the value of "1" to the $Type of all the songs in the dataframe, that are in that list.

So it would look something like this.

```
   Song Type
1     1    1
2     2    1
3    3A   NA
4    9C   NA
5     6    1
6     5   NA
7   12B   NA
8   32A    1
9    18   NA
10   27   NA
11   24   NA
12   1D    1
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match` or `%in%` - `match` returns the positions of match and by default the `nomatch` is `NA`.  Once we get the matching index, create a logical vector with `> 0` and coerce it to binary (`+`)

```
allsongs$Type <- +(match(allsongs$Song, type1songs[[1]]) > 0)
```

-output

```
allsongs
#    Song Type
#1     1    1
#2     2    1
#3    3A   NA
#4    9C   NA
#5     6    1
#6     5   NA
#7   12B   NA
#8   32A    1
#9    18   NA
#10   27   NA
#11   24   NA
#12   1D    1
```

---

Or an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(allsongs)[Song %in% type1songs[[1]], Type := 1]
```

Or with `base R`

```
allsongs$Type[allsongs$Song %in% type1songs[[1]]] <- 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `match` approach by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64234676/12158757), another base R option might be using `factor`, e.g.,

```
within(allsongs, Type <- +(as.integer(factor(Song,levels = type1songs[[1]]))>0))
```

which gives

```
   Song Type
1     1    1
2     2    1
3    3A   NA
4    9C   NA
5     6    1
6     5   NA
7   12B   NA
8   32A    1
9    18   NA
10   27   NA
11   24   NA
12   1D    1
```

Comment: Thank you!! I used the `match` function but I appreciate the options !!